# Google PlaceID pointing to a different location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

We have observed the issue that a Google Place ID changes the location it is pointing to. Is this the expected behavior that a PlaceID my point to a different location after a certain time period?

On 14th March, using Google Maps API, we fetched the PlaceID for a UK Postcode SW46LP. This PlaceID used to access the place details associated withe it. However, now this is returning a different address.

For additional context, we use the `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext`
to get the placeId for a postcode.

The documentations says that PlaceIDs may change over time. developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-id

Is there any way to identify if a certain PlaceID is expiring?

Comment: No, it is not expected.

Comment: *Place IDs may change over time.* - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-id

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the delayed response.

As mentioned, PlaceIDs may change over time, The issue we were seeing was more about placeIDs varying in the same hour of generating them. The issue was not with placeID varying but being inaccurate due to ambiguity in the address provided by the user.

Based on a suggestion by Google, we have added the country code to the address and tried to provide a detailed address for more accurate results.

Answer (score -1):

You should expect to refresh stored Place IDs at least every 12 months. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place-id#refresh-id